Distinguish between windows of applications
I have an problem with distinguishing between windows of Gwenview and Dolphin. See screenshot. What happens is I intend to close Gwenview but I click on the X for Dolphin. One way to help would be to change the color of the window from for either application. Can this be done? Or can you suggest another way to help?

